# Can I re-create node_modules from package-lock.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package-lock.json

I cloned a repository from github which has a package-lock.json (but no package.json). Then in a git bash terminal I go to the directory and run `npm install` but I just get a message saying there is no package.json and then everything in package-lock.json gets deleted so it's basically empty except for the project name and version.

I thought running `npm install` with a package-lock.json in the directory was enough to re-create node_modules, but am I seriously misunderstanding how this works? By the way I have node 8.12.0 and npm 6.4.1 and am running on Windows 10. Also, I think the package-lock.json was created on a unix system so could there be problems when using package-lock.json on a different OS?

I already tried running `npm init` just to get a package.json file and then running `npm install` but that still didn't get me a node_modules folder.

Comment: You could give this package a try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-install - it's not exactly what it is intended for, but if you generate an empty package.json file then run it, it'll add the dependencies to it, so you can then run npm install.

Comment: Thanks that actually did work. `auto-install` did add the dependencies to an empty package.json and even downloaded the packages without having to run `npm install`. This just seems like kind of a weird workaround. I still don't get why `npm install` can't look at package-lock.json and download the dependencies from that.

Comment: Oh good. Do you mind if I add it as an answer then for you to accept?

Comment: Ok go ahead. Technically your solution doesn't really answer the original question since it looks like `auto-install` doesn't even need package-lock.json, but it does solve my original problem of how to get the right packages in node_modules so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the `package-lock.json` file relies on the presence of a `package.json` file, so you'll not be able to recreate your `node_modules` folder from the `package-lock.json` file alone (happy to be proved wrong here).

Therefore, your best bet is to (mis)use a module like [auto-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-install) that is capable of generating the `package.json` file based on a project's dependencies, as they appear in the files.

Install it globally (`npm install -g auto-install`), then you'll need to generate an empty `package.json` file for it to run (use `npm init -y` in your project root). Kick things off with the command `auto-install` and it should add the dependencies to the `package.json` file.

HTH

Answer (score 5):

Starting from Mar 5, 2018, you can run `npm ci` to install packages from package-lock.json.

> npm ci bypasses a package’s package.json to install modules from a
>   package’s lockfile.

https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171556855892/introducing-npm-ci-for-faster-more-reliable

Comment: trying in 6.9.0 does not do so.

Comment: @RuiDC npm ci has been existed since from v5.7.0 https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171139955345/v570

Comment: `npm ci` will compare `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, thus it refuses to run if `package.json` is absent.

Answer (score 3):

`package-lock.json` records the exact version and url of packages need to install, thus you can use npm to install them accordingly:

- npm can install from urls that point to tarballs
- `--no-package-lock` option to tell npm to not touch `package-lock.json` file

For example, to install all packages in `package-lock.json`:

```sh
cat package-lock.json | jq '.dependencies[].resolved' | xargs npm i --no-package-lock
```

`jq` is a command line tool to pares `jq`, you can write a simple JavaScript script to parse it instead (if you do not want to install `jq` or learn jq's query syntax).